# What is the purpose of "mark-as-read" page?

Tags: support, hidden-features

Going over my inbox, I noticed a weird link for the "bounty expires" item:

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=6&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f177639%2fcannot-log-in-with-ipad-anymore
```

What is the purpose of this "mark-as-read"? Browsing to it [directly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read) or [providing a dummy `messagetypeid`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=999) leads to a plain "true" response. Appending any Stack Exchange page as value of `returnurl` will cause a redirection to that page. External links have no effect.

Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Just a wild guess, but I bet it's to mark your bounty notification as read - I *think* you have to click on the link to dismiss the little blue bubble.

Comment: Will check it next time but I'm pretty sure that like all other items it's marked as read once I open the inbox.

Comment: And another wild guess: once marked as read, you might no longer get the same notification by email? (That might explain the difference with the other items. Note that the message is NOT removed from one's Inbox when clicked, which I guess might also have made some sense.)

Comment: @Arjan excellent observation, just confirmed I didn't get email for the last couple of bounty messages. Will you post it as answer, hopefully to have official confirmation at some point?

Comment: You're the one who investigated, @ShaWizDowArd ;-) (I'm running to work now.)